# Terraform Variables prompting me when defined in tfvars

Tags: variables, google-cloud-platform, terraform

There is something that I am not understanding about terraform variables.  I am getting prompted for two variables in when I run "terraform apply".   I don't think that I should be prompted for any as I defined a terraform.tfvars.  I am getting prompted for (applicationNamespace, and staticIpName) but I am not sure why.  What am I misunderstanding?

I created a file (terraform.tfvars):

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------
# General
#--------------------------------------------------------------
cluster = "reddiyo-development"
project = "<MYPROJECTID>"
region  = "us-central1"
credentialsLocation = "<MYCERTLOCATION>"
bucket = "reddiyo-terraform-state"
vpcLocation = "us-central1-b"
network = "default"
staticIpName = "dev-env-ip"
#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Specific To NODE
#--------------------------------------------------------------
terraformPrefix = "development"
mainNodeName = "primary-pool"
nodeMachineType = "n1-standard-1"
#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Specific To Application
#--------------------------------------------------------------
applicationNamespace = "application"
```

I also have a terrform script:

```
variable "cluster" {}
variable "project" {}
variable "region" {}
variable "bucket" {}
variable "terraformPrefix" {}
variable "mainNodeName" {}
variable "vpcLocation" {}
variable "nodeMachineType" {}
variable "credentialsLocation" {}
variable "network" {}
variable "applicationNamespace" {}
variable "staticIpName" {}


data "terraform_remote_state" "remote" {
  backend = "gcs"
  config = {
    bucket = "${var.bucket}"
    prefix = "${var.terraformPrefix}"
  }
}

provider "google" {
  //This needs to be updated to wherever you put your credentials
  credentials = "${file("${var.credentialsLocation}")}"
  project     = "${var.project}"
  region      = "${var.region}"
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "gke-cluster" {
  name     = "${var.cluster}"
  network  = "${var.network}"
  location   = "${var.vpcLocation}"

  remove_default_node_pool = true

  # node_pool {
  #   name = "${var.mainNodeName}"
  # }
  node_locations = [
    "us-central1-a",
    "us-central1-f"
  ]
  //Get your credentials for the newly created cluster so that microservices can be deployed
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "gcloud config set project ${var.project}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${var.cluster} --zone ${var.vpcLocation}"
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_pool" {
  name       = "${var.mainNodeName}"
  cluster    = "${var.cluster}"
  location   = "${var.vpcLocation}"
  node_count = "2"

  node_config {
    machine_type = "${var.nodeMachineType}"

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append",
    ]
  }

  management {
    auto_repair  = true
    auto_upgrade = true
  }
  autoscaling {
    min_node_count = 2
    max_node_count = 10
  }
}

# //Reserve a Static IP
resource "google_compute_address" "ip_address" {
  name = "${var.staticIpName}"
}

//Install Ambassador
module "ambassador" {
  source      = "modules/ambassador"
  applicationNamespace = "${var.applicationNamespace}"
}
```

Comment: What does your directory structure look like and can you show the output of running `terraform plan -input=false`?

Comment: Are you actually passing a value for these variables or did you just define them?

Comment: SO....    I am an idiot.   I had a copy of the terraform.tfvars in a different folder and was updating that one.   When I put the variable in the correct file then (shocker of shocker) it worked.    Thank you for helping me see the forest through the trees.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to force it to read your variables by using:

```
terraform apply -var-file=<path_to_your_vars>
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference, read below, if anybody face the similar issue.

“terraform.tfvars” is the default variable file name, from where terraform will read variables.

If any other file name is used, it needs to be passed in the command line i.e: “terraform plan –var=whateverName.tfvars

Also, order of Loading for variables by Terraform program.

1. Environment Variables
2. terraform.tfvars
3. terraform.tfvars.json
4. Any .auto.tfvars
5. Any –var or –var-file options

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).